# Immediate App Crash at Splash Screen

Tags: ios, crash, app-store, xamarin, app-store-connect

We submitted our app update (1.01) to the App Store on Wednesday of last week. The app included a few major bug and authentication fixes. We submitted our working/bug-free app to the App Store via the normal procedure. Sunday night at 8:31PM EST we saw that the status of our app went to "In Review". Then at 9:17PM EST the app was approved and the status changed to "Processing for App Store".

All users who now go into the App Store and download the 1.01 update are seeing the app open the immediately crash at the splash screen. We've tested this on multiple devices and all 1.01 updates crash immediately. We submitted our distribution-ready app in a working state, there were no crashes or bugs on our end.

Knowing that the app was under review for nearly and hour reiterates that the app was in a working/crash-free state upon submission. We've read of a few cases where other apps were submitted, approved and the app would crash upon opening the. We're looking to you for a quick resolution to this App Store issue.

Are there ways to revert to 1.0? Any assistance would be helpful?

Comment: Install an old version of the app, then install the new app from the App Store. Let it crash, then look in Xcode for the crash log and you'll have an idea of what could be the cause. It's hard to tell without code, but my initial guess is that it has something to do with persistent data (e.g., outdated Core Data model).

Comment: Agree with @Scott. You probably have Core Data in your app that you've updated. And if so, the reason for the crash is mostly likely due to lack of Core Data migration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of reverting to previous versions :( You can only remove app from store but as I understand this is not the case. From my own experience I can say that the review team doesn't always find bugs in apps under review and this is how it actually ends with not working app and irritated customers.

Comment: "I can say that the review team doesn't always find bugs" -- The review teams job is not to find bugs, that's yours.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot revert.  However you can fix the issue and request an expedited review cycle.  https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite

Sidenote - do you use Core Data? Maybe a migration failed?  This is pretty common if you changed the data model.  If the reviewers just installed the new version without upgrading, they wouldn't have seen the crash.  Could explain that... I have a hard time believing they would have passed a launch crash that they observed.